# Magic: The Gathering - Does Captivating Crew's ability resolve if I bounce it in response?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has [Captivating Crew](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCaptivating%20Crew%5d) in play.

They activate the ability to take control of one of my creatures.

In response I play [Perilous Voyage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPerilous%20Voyage%5d) and bounce the Captivating Crew back to their hand.

Do they still gain control of my creature?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they still gain control of your creature.

> 112.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won't affect the ability.

This is the same for any sort of ability; removing the source does nothing to the ability itself.

Comment: Caveat: In a multiplayer game, if the player who owns the ability loses while it's on the stack, the ability goes away. So in that sense it doesn't exist _entirely_ independently of its source.

Comment: @Arthur, You merely demonstrated it doesn't exist independently of its owner. As the rules say, it exists independently of its source.